# out.print not pushing the data to browser

Tags: jsp, buffer, flush, server-push

I have a JSP with `while (true)` where data is sent to browser . code snippet

```
while (true) {
    out.print("pushing some data to browser");
    out.flush();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

It works most the time but rarely the data is not sent to the browser at 1 second interval.

Rather than it is queued up and throws all data at a same time.

Comment: What is the motivation for sending data periodically? Are you trying to implement a Comet messaging system?

Comment: i am using this loop as pushlet concept (pushing the data from server to client)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explaination why its not working :
JSP is a servlet object at runtime and JSP scriplet/expressions are getting called as part of service() method of Servlet object.

In this case when you access JSP page it will call service() method and keep appending data to out stream until thread is interrupted by app server(InterruptedException) finally it renders page and shows data at once.

You should consider implementing CommetServlet by extending HttpServlet which can leavarage app server support.

App Server comet support examples:

- Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.htm
- Jetty:http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/continuation/ContinuationSupport.html
- Resin : http://caucho.com/resin-3.1/examples/servlet-comet/